# Como armar una fracción como una lista y retorarla - PYTHON

Tags: python

> Lo que comprendí es crear una lista donde se almacenen las fracciones, teniendo en cuenta que tienen Numerador y Denominador. (x,y). Luego, me estanque al saber como hacerlo con una lista y tupla anidada de la siguiente manera [ (x,y), (a,b) ]

```
 def cargarFraccion(num,deno): #Funcion de carga

        lista = []
    
        lista.append((num))
        lista.append((deno))
    
        print (lista)
    
    
    
    
    
    cargarFraccion(1,2)
```

Comment: Forma la tupla normalmente y luego agregala a la lista. Me explico?

Comment: `lista.append( (num, deno) )`